# Is there a way to get Cuda support for an older GeForce GT?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, cuda

An older GPU doesn't seem to support Cuda? I am under the understanding that Cuda is only software so I assume it could somehow be forced to use it.

It's an [GeForce GT 530](https://www.pc-specs.com/gpu/Nvidia/500_Series/GeForce_GT_530/466)

PS: I've been told that my logic is deeply flawed but haven't got a coherent reason why

Comment: CUDA may be a software library, but it depends on hardware features and capabilities. If it were "only software" then it could run on AMD as well as Nvidia, but this is not the case. Your logic is based on a flawed initial premise, but if that premise were correct then your logic would be correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is a programming interface created by Nvidia for Nvidia graphics cards.

> The CUDA platform is a software layer that gives direct access to the GPU's virtual instruction set and parallel computational elements, for the execution of compute kernels.

As such the programming interface requires awareness and support of the underlying hardware. It is not "simply" programming, it is programming combined with a compiler that can create programs specific to the graphics card cores.

> CUDA provides both a **low level API (CUDA Driver API**, non single-source) and a higher level API (CUDA Runtime API, single-source)

What you are thinking of as just an API is the higher level API, you still need drivers for the lower-level hardware. Lacking those drivers, or lacking the hardware support for newer functions required by those drivers will mean that your program will not be able to be run on your desired target.

That said, your graphics card *should* support CUDA, but you may be restricted to an older version of the API and so may not have access to newer functionality.

From that Wikipedia page there is a GPU support list that shows what [CUDA version is supported by a given graphics card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) and it appears that the GT530 is not listed, possibly due to it being an OEM card. [Techpowerup](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gt-530-oem.c630) state that it should support CUDA 2.1.

As mentioned in a comment by [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) on your [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115322/is-there-a-way-to-modify-an-older-geforce-gt-to-support-cuda) you probably need to go back to a slightly older version of the CUDA development toolkit:

> you(r) GPU does have CUDA support, however because of its age support was ended for it at the beginning of 2019. As a result you need to use an older toolkit and driver which has support for the Fermi architecture